# how to deal with multiple possible null on angular template

Tags: angular

When an error occurs in a template, all the templates stop working properly.

What do you do about it?

In this particular example, a server returned a json object with a null property which caused an error on a template.

Only thing I can think of doing is validating data on the component or the template and working accordingly case by case, but is there any other way to deal with this problem?

```
my.component.html:39 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null
 at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (my.component.html:40)
 at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (services.ts:307)
 at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
 at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
 at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:670)
 at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:389)
 at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
 at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
 at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
 at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
 at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:670)
 at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:389)
 at callViewAction (view.ts:700)
 at execComponentViewsAction (view.ts:644)
 at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:392)
```

Comment: why not using `ngIf`?

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Dealing with null property paths at Angular

**1. Using safe navigation operator:**

> The safe navigation operator (?) means that the employer field is
>   optional and if undefined, the rest of the expression should be
>   ignored.

```
<p>Employer: {{employer?.companyName}}</p>
```

**2. Using `ngIf`**

> Removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on the
>   showSection expression.

```
<section *ngIf="showSection">
```

Reference [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)