# Angular: Type checking in templates not working correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tslint

Since some time the type checking does not work in the templates of Angular in VSCode.

I have the following code:

```html
<div *ngIf="activeProperty" class="mx-3">
    <!-- some other code -->
    <input
        required
        id="propertyName"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="propertyName"
        [ngModel]="activeProperty.uiProperty.label"
        (ngModelChange)="updateLabelAndKeyInSpec($event)"
    />
</div>
```

Now at this line:

`[ngModel]="activeProperty.uiProperty.label"`

`activeProperty` is underlined, telling me that `The expression might be null` which is clearly wrong because I'm checking that by the `*ngIf` above.

Please see my `ng --version` here:

```
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.6
Node: 12.7.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.6
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.6
@angular/cdk                      8.2.2
@angular/cli                      8.3.6
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.6
@schematics/angular               8.3.6
@schematics/update                0.803.6
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The expression might be null - where did you get this error?

Comment: VS Code is complaining, so I assume it's a `tslint` error

Comment: [ngModel]="activeProperty?.uiProperty?.label" can you try this way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869170/how-to-deal-with-multiple-possible-null-on-angular-template

Comment: @hrdkisback Thanks, but I read this before. As you can see the `*ngIf` does not solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah safe navigation operator (?) would works. However, you can check and try this. `*ngIf="activeProperty && activeProperty.uiProperty"`

Comment: This does not solve the issue... That's exactly the problem: The assignment in `[ngModel]` does not seem to care about `*ngIf` statemens. Plus, the error is because `activeProperty` might be null, so it has nothing to do with `uiProperty` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you in detail why it's underlined... Maybe because it doesn"t know of the `*ngIf` or so... but this should fix the issue:

```
[ngModel]="activeProperty?.uiProperty?.label"
```

Comment: This works, thank you. However, when I put a two way binding (`[(ngModel)]`) I cannot use the question mark. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you shouldn't be able to use it there... Can you share your tslint.json? https://jsonblob.com/

Comment: It's giving me an error `Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 31 in [activeProperty?.uiControlType=$event] in ...`

My tslint is huge, but if it helps to debug I can share it. Please let me know :)

Comment: you wrote it like that though: `<input [(ngModel)]="activeProperty?.uiProperty?.label">` right? And where does the error come from? tslint or somewhere else?

Comment: Where? Please check my thread, I just have a `[ngModel]` binding.

Comment: but we're talkin about the two way binding right now, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206429/discussion-between-chrnx-and-dave0688).

Answer (score 0):

you can use activeProperty!.uiProperty!.label

Answer (score 0):

Typescript type narrowing doesn't work with `*ngIf` the same way that it works with the native `if` statement.

You can get around it by using "as":

```
<div *nIf="path.to.my.property as myProperty">
  <!-- use "myProperty" here, typescript will understand it's not null -->
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[(ngModel)]="activeProperty.uiProperty.label"
```

Can you try this?

Comment: This is just the binding, which has nothing to do with that issue unfortunately